# Woocomerce downloadable pdf with sample pdf to check if its good for purchase or not

Tags: woocommerce, digital

I have created a product which is a book, and user can download that book by purchasing it, but I want to show the user some samples of the PDF pages.

If the user finds the sample interesting then the user can purchase the full book. Please suggest how can I do this

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add a download link for the sample pdf in you product short description or if you are your theme has light box support `add_theme_support( 'wc-product-gallery-lightbox' );` you could always add the sample pages as part of the gallery and the user could read them from the light box